# Example of java web client Using ws02 identity server

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am looking for authentication and authorizing solution.

I crossed by WS02.

Our web app clients implemented in Java and .net

I tried to look for an example of a Java web application which integrates with the WS02 identity server.

Is it even possible? In case it is, are there any libraries I can download in order to integrate between our web client and the identity server?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server's APIs have been exposed as web service APIs.  Basically to authenticate to the Identity Server, you can use "AuthenticationAdmin" web service. Also there is a user management web service called "RemoteUserStoreManagerService" where WSO2 Identity Server's user store has been exposed via web service [1]. For authorization,  you can probably look for XACML. XACML is the de-factor standard for it. WSO2 Identity Server exposes "EntitlementService" [2] as XACML authorization decision query point.

If you want to call these web services, you need to write a typical web service client program. (You may need to authenticate to server using basic auth).These web services even can be tested using soap UI.  You can find java client program for "RemoteUserStoreManagerService" service from here [1]. If you are witting a java client, following [3] would be minim libraries that you needed. But "Stub" jar file must be related with the service that you are invoking.  You can look for the code and see what is happening there to get more understanding

[1] https://github.com/soasecurity/soasecurity/tree/master/user-mgt/client/remote-user-400

[2] http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/06/14/pep-client-for-wso2is-pdp/

[3] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pap/4.2.X/lib/